# How Can I delete item on my SQliteOpenhelper

Tags: java, android

I save my recyclerview with SQliteopenhelper . I can add item with edittext varibles . I use Itemtouchhelper for swip to delete item . **How can ı delete item on SQliteopenhelper** . Can you be fast

**todoactivity.java**

```
   public class todoactivity extends AppCompatActivity    {
    TextView title;
    Button back;
    ImageButton gorevo;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<String>Listsx = new ArrayList<>();
    TodoActivityAdpter adapterx;
    DatabaseHelper4 myDBxxx;
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    long id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todoactivity);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewxx);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        adapterx=new TodoActivityAdpter(Listsx);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterx);
        title=findViewById(R.id.titlex);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.text_viewx);
        gorevo = findViewById(R.id.gorevo);

        myDBxxx = new DatabaseHelper4(this);

        Cursor datax = myDBxxx.getListContents();
        if(datax.getCount() == 0){

        }else{
            while(datax.moveToNext()){
                Listsx.add(datax.getString(1));

                ListAdapter listAdapterx = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.todoactivity_item,R.id.textitem,Listsx);
                adapterx.notifyItemInserted(Listsx.size()-1);
            }
        }


        gorevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(todoactivity.this);
                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheetlayout3);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                EditText editText = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.editx);
                Button ekle = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.ekle);
                ekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        Listsx.add(text);
                        AddDataxxx(text);
                        adapterx.notifyItemInserted(Listsx.size()-1);
                        bottomSheetDialog.hide();
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        back=findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(todoactivity.this, pomodoroscreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        });



        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                int positionx = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                Listsx.remove(positionx);
                adapterx.notifyItemRemoved(positionx);
                int id = recyclerView.getChildAt(positionx).getId();
                myDBxxx.deleteItem(id);
               

}
};
        
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void AddDataxxx(String newEntry) {

        boolean insertDatax = myDBxxx.addDataxxx(newEntry);
    }


}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper4 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME4 = "mylistxxx.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME4 = "mylist_dataxxx";
    public static final String COL14 = "iDxxx";
    public static final String COL24 = "ITEM1xxx";


    public DatabaseHelper4(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME4, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dbxxx) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME4 + " (iDxxx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " ITEM1xxx TEXT)";
        dbxxx.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dbxxx, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        dbxxx.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME4);
        onCreate(dbxxx);
    }

    public boolean addDataxxx(String textt) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbxxx = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL24, textt);

        long result = dbxxx.insert(TABLE_NAME4, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase dbxxx = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor dataxxx = dbxxx.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME4, null);
        return dataxxx;
    }
public void deleteItem(int iDxxx) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME4 + " WHERE " + COL14 + " = " +
            iDxxx);
}


}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class TodoActivityAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoActivityAdpter.Holder> {



    List<String>Listsx;
    public TodoActivityAdpter(List<String>itemxxx){
        this.Listsx = itemxxx;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TodoActivityAdpter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.todoactivity_item,parent,false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TodoActivityAdpter.Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(Listsx.get(position));


        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {


                    holder.textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                } else {
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Color_black));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Listsx.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;

        List<String>Listsx;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        Context mContext;
        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);

            textView=view.findViewById(R.id.text_viewx);
            checkBox=view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewxx);



        }
    }
}
```

Thats my java classes . My activity is **todoactivity** . My SQliteopenhelper is **DatabaseHelper.java** . My Adapter is **adapter.java** . I can delete item on my recyclerview but ı cant delete item on my database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily delete item from your table by just below code.

//Add method in your database class.

```
public void deleteItem(int iDxxx) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME4 + " WHERE " + COL14 + " = 
" + iDxxx);
}
```

and Just Call this method from where you are deleting item.

Comment: thanks but what will i add to activty

Comment: Call above method with id

Comment: ı was try this but it cant work myDBxxx.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

Comment: I can delete this on my  list but I cant delete this on my database

Comment: Your adapter position is genrated by your recyclerview. You require id (iDxxx) to delete it from your database.

Comment: But How can I get id

Comment: Can you generate one other question for it. it is different from your current question. I will add my answer there.Actually you will get particular item data from Adapter.

Comment: Or you can search from "How to get Particular data from Adapter.If you are generating new question then please share your question link here.

Comment: thats cant work

Comment: I Can you look now . I edited my Quastion . Can you Look my codes . I still cant delete item on my databasehelper

Comment: if you will pass anything else instead of your id then it will not work. in Android you have Database Inspector. look there your id and try to give your id in this method and see this delete code is working or not.

Comment: this method is tested by me. and it is working well. but you send something else instead of id then how it will work.it cant work by somthing .it can only delete data from your existing database

Comment: My answer is correct ,it is not working because your send position not id. How can your id is your position?

Comment: add existing id manually and look your item is deleting from database or not.

Comment: ok I will try this

Comment: Yeah its working I add "1" for id . It's work sucsesfull

Comment: As per your question my answer is perfect. you are having another problem. you are not getting id here you require that. My answer is perfect please accept it.

Comment: Ok I will look at